# задачка на замыкание

Tags: javascript, замыкания

что то в последнее время не часто с js сталкиваюсь, поэтому многие вещи подзабыл,
и вот, попалась мне одна вроде бы тривиальная задачка.

какое должно быть тело функции чтобы был вывод как в комментах в коде

```
var summator = function(val) {
   //
};

console.log(summator(1)); // 1
console.log(summator(5)); // 6
console.log(summator(3)); // 9
```

пока пришёл к довольно колхозному решению

```
var summator = function(val) {
  if (typeof summator.sum === 'undefined')
    summator.sum = 0;

  summator.sum += val;

  return summator.sum;
};
```

как написать при помощи замыканий ?

Comment: а минус за что вот ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вам нужно так или иначе выделить аккумулятор, в котором будет храниться сумма. Как вы правильно написали, это делается через замыкание - с применением промежуточной анонимной функции, в которой и будет создан аккумулятор

```
var summator = (function() {
    var accumulator = 0;
    return function (increment) {
        return accumulator += increment;
    }
})();
```

С ES6 это можно сократить до однострочника

```
var summator = ((accumulator) => i => accumulator += i)(0)
```

Comment: блин, и правда очень тривиальное решение

Comment: я знал что нужно внутри функии накапливать сумму но как это выразить в коде...вот где проблема была. давно на js не писал

Answer (score 0):

```js
let value = 0;

const summator = function (val) {
  value = value + val;
  return value
};
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять немного более развернутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав кнопку [edit].